# Allow users to choose which layout to be applied

Tags: theming

Is there any way to allow users to choose which layout to be applied (Omit the given media queries) for the Omega theme?

For example, ESPN has a switcher for choosing the layout: When browsing in iPad, it has a link to switch to desktop.

[image: screenshot]

Do you have any idea on how achieving such functionality with the Omega theme?

Answer (score 1):

Responsive designs usually rely on media queries to apply the styles, but you could make a copy of those styles and prefix its selectors with `body.desktop`. Then, when you want iPad users to see different styles, just add the class to the `body` element (using jQuery). CSS preprocessors like SASS will help you mantain those styles without duplicating the code — [Zen 7.x-5.x](http://drupal.org/project/zen) has awesome out-of-the-box support to SASS/Compass and responsive designs. See the [Sassy](http://drupal.org/project/sassy) module as well.

There is also the adaptive design approach: it relies on browser sniffing to return device-specific markup and styles. The [mobile tools](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools) module will surely help should you choose this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i think it does not address problem to my question. We are using Omega theme which already comes with media quieries and different stylesheets for each layout. The question is more on how to allow user MANUALLY switch stylesheet.

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting: put a widget that adds a class to the layout, use that class to trigger a layout change in CSS. You can't trigger media queries directly (afaik).